# Using LINQ to pull MembershipUser.Username into a new object

Tags: linq

I have the following code and I need to pull out each user's username from the membership tables:

```
var results = (from u in db.U_USER
               where u.Forename.ToLower().Contains(search)
               || u.Surname.ToLower().Contains(search)
               select new ExUser
               {
                   MembershipId = u.MembershipId,
                   Surname = u.Surname,
                   Forename = u.Forename,
                   Username = Membership.GetUser(u.MembershipId).UserName
               });
```

Now I know *why* im getting the following, but can anybody recommend a solution?

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser GetUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is **trying to translate your select expression** into T-SQL, which it can't because there's no ExUser etc. in T-SQL.

Finhish off the expression with a call to `AsEnumerable` or similar, and then perform the projection:

```
var results = (from u in db.U_USER
               where u.Forename.ToLower().Contains(search)
               || u.Surname.ToLower().Contains(search)
               select u)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(u => new ExUser
              {
                  MembershipId = u.MembershipId,
                  Surname = u.Surname,
                  Forename = u.Forename,
                  Username = Membership.GetUser(u.MembershipId).UserName
              });
```

Comment: Fantastic guys, this did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by forcing the results into memory by using `AsEnumerable`. When the results are in memory you can call `Membership.GetUser` without linq attempting to translate it to sql:

```
var results = (from u in db.U_USER                        
                where u.Forename.ToLower().Contains(search) || u.Surname.ToLower().Contains(search)
               ).AsEnumerable().Select(u => new ExUser {
                MembershipId = u.MembershipId,                             
                Surname = u.Surname,                             
                Forename = u.Forename,                             
                Username = Membership.GetUser(u.MembershipId).UserName                        
                });
```